# Multisite use language code as subdirectory

Tags: multisite, multi-language, language

I installed WordPress in the subdiretory `/de` and activated multisite features. The main blog has the URL/path: `mysite.de/de`

Now I want to add a second site for the English language with the following url: `mysite.de/en`

But after I added the site, the subdirectory for the English site was set as: 
`mysite.de/de/en`

Any ideas how I can get these site urls?

```
mysite.de/de
mysite.de/en
mysite.de/fr
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's a proper multisite solution:

**Install WordPress** directly on the root of your domain `mysite.de`. After that, setup a multisite and chose the **subdomain** option (Yes, subdomain! It's far more flexible and you can use it with subdirectories as well).

WordPress will ask you to update `wp-config.php` and `.htaccess`. To the `wp-config.php` add the following constants (in addition to the one provided by WP)

```
define( "COOKIEDOMAIN", "" );
define( "ADMIN_COOKIE_PATH", "/" );
define( 'SITECOOKIEPATH', '/' );
```

Don't use the .htaccess code provided by WordPress but use **instead** this one:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(.*\.php)$ $2 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

**Go to the network admin menu** and create two sites, one for each language. You will get asked for the site address (subdomain). Just enter `de` for the German site and `en` for the English one. After the site has been created, edit it directly. *Now* you can edit the complete URL. Just set it to `http://mysite.de/de` and `http://mysite.de/en`. Do this for the French site as well.

Now you have four sites in your network, probably with the following IDs:

```
1 mysite.de/
2 mysite.de/de
3 mysite.de/en
4 mysite.de/fr
```

As you don't need the first one, you can leave it just empty. You just don't use it. Manage your content in the other thre sites.

To redirect requests to `mysite.de/` add another line to your `.htaccess` above the others:

```
RedirectMatch permanent "^/$" http://mysite.de/de
```

You now have a full functional network of two active sites for your content.

Finally a personal recommendation: There's a free plugin called [Multilingual Press](https://wordpress.org/plugins/multilingual-press/) that supports this concept of a multilingual setup in a network. Disclosure: I contributed to this plugin before and working for a company that develops this plugin.

Answer (score 0):

It would be far easier to maintain the blog by using a good WordPress translation plugin.

WPML ([http://wpml.org](http://wpml.org/)) is my favourite plugin for the task. If you prefer not to pay anything [QTranslate](http://wordpress.org/plugins/qtranslate) is also a good option.

Both plugins allow you to have sub domains (en.mysite.de) or language folders (mysite.de/en).

Best of luck!

Comment: These plugins might offer a solution for multilingual websites, but they does not solve the problem at all.